# Unable to deploy Apex-based sharing code due to sObject Type not Supported

Tags: deployment, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

I am trying to deploy some Apex-based sharing.  Everything works fine in sandbox and code is 100% covered. I have a set of contacts (with a related User field) and a set of Project Task records (a Private object).  Both the Contact records and the Project Task records have a matching Department picklist.  I have triggers on both objects executing @future methods to do the following:

- Share the Project Task with the related users of all Contact records with a matching department after Project Task insert (or update on Department change) if they haven't been shared the record already

  - Share all Project Tasks with the related user when a new Contact is inserted that match that Contact's department.

Everything works perfectly in sandbox, but I get this error upon deployment for both methods:

> sObject type 'pse__Project_Task__Share' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I'm getting the error specifically when I first query the Share object to see what records exist already:

```
for(pse__Project_Task__Share pts : [SELECT ParentId, UserOrGroupId
                                            FROM pse__Project_Task__Share
                                            WHERE ParentId IN : taskMap.keyset()])
```

Comment: Check if "pse__Project_Task" object exist in production? or you are deploying object and this code component altogether?

Comment: The object exists in production (pse__Project_Task__c).  Oh, you know what you made me think of... I think I didn't include the Sharing Reason in the change set!  That might be why the Share object doesn't exist.  Checking.

Comment: Is sharing enabled in production for that object? In production?

Comment: I had not yet made the object private in production.  OWD was still public read/write.  As soon as I made it private it worked fine.  Lesson learned.  Thank you kurunve and Santanu Boral for getting me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

So if it helps anybody else this was because I still had the OWD for the object as Public Read/Write in production, where I had made it Private in sandbox.  Apparently the related __Share object doesn't exist if the object in question has never been private.  As soon as I made the object private in production it worked fine.  Thanks.

Comment: If you've solved your own issue, you should [accept](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer, so that the question falls out of the "Unanswered Questions" list.